# Failed to play mp3 in AngularJS for android device

Tags: angularjs

I want to play a mp3 track, have code like this:

```
var audio = new Audio("file:///Internal Memory/Notifications/msg.mp3");
audio.play();
```

the path is found in my explorer, but it's failed to play the mp3.

Why？ (I guess it's the path problem?) Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your audio file on your webserver and try calling it with an `http` url, not a local `file://` one.

ex:

```
var audio = new Audio("http://example.com/Notifications/msg.mp3");
audio.play();
```

or:

```
var audio = new Audio("Notifications/msg.mp3");
audio.play();
```

Comment: don't you have a webserver ? Where do you put your html and js then ?